# Winsock android bluetooth connection error

Tags: android, bluetooth, kivy, winsock

I am working on a project in which my PC acts as a bluetooth server and my android phone as a bluetooth client

I am using winsock for my PC and I coded the android app using python and using the android java apis with help of pyjnius

The app gets terminated in the connect() method

The logcat file says

JVM exception occurred: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

The code for bluetooth server is below....first I lookup for remote devices and then do the socket operations

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2bth.h>
#include<bluetoothapis.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define SUCCESS 0

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "irprops.lib")

int main()
{
    CHAR buf[5000];
    //  LPTSTR s;
    WCHAR addressAsString[1000];
    BTH_ADDR b;
    WSADATA data;
    int result, i = 0, channel = 30;
    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
    if (result != SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "error occured while initialising winsock...";
        Sleep(1000);
        exit(result);
    }
    cout << "winsock initialisation successful\n";
    WSAQUERYSET queryset;
    memset(&queryset, 0, sizeof(WSAQUERYSET));
    queryset.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    queryset.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    HANDLE hLookup;
    result = WSALookupServiceBegin(&queryset, LUP_CONTAINERS, &hLookup);
    if (result != SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "error in initialising look up service\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        exit(result);
    }
    cout << "initialising lookup service successful\n";

    BYTE buffer[4096];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    DWORD bufferLength = sizeof(buffer);
    LPWSAQUERYSET pResults = (LPWSAQUERYSET)buf;
    BTH_ADDR my_add;
    while (!WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE, &bufferLength, pResults))
    {
        LPTSTR name = pResults->lpszServiceInstanceName;
        BTH_ADDR b = ((SOCKADDR_BTH *)pResults->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr)->btAddr;
        wcout << hex << name << "\t" << b << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        if (!lstrcmp(name, L"Anjali Mohanty (SM-G36"))
        {
            my_add = b;
        }
    }
    WSALookupServiceEnd(hLookup);

    SOCKET server_socket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    cout << "server socket created" << endl;

    //SOCKET ADDRESS INFORMATION
    SOCKADDR_BTH addr;
    addr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    addr.btAddr = 0;
    addr.serviceClassId = GUID_NULL;
    addr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    cout << "Socket address information is stored" << endl;

    bind(server_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));
    cout << "server socket binding complete"<<endl;
    listen(server_socket, SOMAXCONN);
    GUID my_guid = { 0x00001101, 0x0000, 0x1000, 0x8000, 0x00, 0x80, 0x5F, 0x9B, 0x34, 0xFB };
    //SET WSA SERVICE
    WSAQUERYSET wsaqueryset = { 0 };
    wsaqueryset.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    wsaqueryset.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    wsaqueryset.lpszServiceInstanceName = L"BT Service"; // Can be anything
    wsaqueryset.lpszComment = L"bt"; //Can be anything
    wsaqueryset.lpServiceClassId = &my_guid;
    wsaqueryset.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 1;
    cout << "WSA service is set" << endl;

    //CONTAINS INFORMATION ABOUT BLUETOOTH BROADCAST SERVICE
    CSADDR_INFO addrInfo = { 0 };
    addrInfo.LocalAddr.lpSockaddr = (SOCKADDR*)&addr;
    addrInfo.LocalAddr.iSockaddrLength = sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH);
    addrInfo.iSocketType = SOCK_STREAM;
    addrInfo.iProtocol = BTHPROTO_RFCOMM;
    cout << "Information about bluetooth broadcast service is stored" << endl;

    //INITIALISE BLUETOOTH SERVICE
    wsaqueryset.lpcsaBuffer = &addrInfo;
    WSASetService(&wsaqueryset, RNRSERVICE_REGISTER, 0);
    cout << "Bluetooth service is initialised" << endl;

    cout << "Waiting for client" << endl;
    SOCKET accept_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, 0);
    cout << "connection accepted" << endl;
}
```

The method in the python android app contains

```
mac_add="C0:CB:38:DD:E1:69"
str_add=String(mac_add)
bd=self.bta.getRemoteDevice(str_add)
self.ids.l2.text="Bluetooth device created"
uuid=UUID.fromString('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB')
bs=bd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
self.ids.l3.text="Bluetooth socket created"
bs.connect()
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: And your server (C program) is still running once you try to connect from your python client? If not, I would say that this is an expected behavior, because your server (executable) is terminated once accept() unblocks.